# DocuSign Connect Service

Tags: docusignapi

I have been using DocuSign Connect feature to get the recipient and envelope status updates.
I have developed an .aspx application to work as a listener which accepts XML transactions sent from DocuSign Connect service. Within my application, I parse the XML and update the statuses of recipients as well as envelopes.

At times, when we get too many updates from Connect service, my application is unable to process the XML and errors out. This happens specially when I get an update for the same envelope for the recipient within a fraction of second. At times, the recipient is the same as sender so I get two notifications if an envelope gets created. My application can only process one XML and fails to process another one as it receives another one right after.
Is there anything specific that I should be doing in my aspx application?

I was also reading the Connect guide and found out that I can also create SOAP interface that uses SOAP API to get Connect updates. How this is different than the listener application that I have created? Are there any advantages of using one over the other? If I use this, will it solve my problem?

Besides Connect, I also create envelopes using event notifications and found the same issue with it.

Please advise,

Minal

Comment: I'm not sure if the SOAP method will solve your issue, it might, but what events are you filtering in your Connect settings in the Console?  Why does the recipient get two emails, because you are filtering for `Envelope Sent` event and `Recipient Sent` Event?  What happens if you disable one of those?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.
The events that I am filtering in the Connect configuration are..
Envelope Completed, Recipient sent, delivered,signed,declined and enveloped voided.
As you suggested, I eliminated the envelope sent notification from my Connect configuration as it is 
the same as recipient sent.

I get multiple updates for the same recipient for the envelope as the recipient is also the sender
of an envelope.I also have multiple recipients to sign the envelope in the same order so I get sent
notification from the Connect service for all the recipients at the same time.

Comment: I am still having issues with Connect update process. I filtered events as per your suggestions but I still get multiple updates when there are more than one recipient in the same order to sign. When once recipient completes signing and other two receives the envelope to sign..I also have tried creating different configurations for Envelope completed status and other recipient statuses..not sure why  my process is not able to process multiple updates..please advise..

Comment: Please reach out to your DS Account Manager for help resolving this issue.  Seems like a deeper issue that a solution engineer needs to look at and help debug.  If you don't have an account manager start with `support@docusign.com` and they can get you in touch with an AM.

Answer (score 0):

the most common cause we see is that listeners do their post processing before sending the success response and there is a time out. You should respond with success that you got the message and do your processing in a separate thread.